# How to Prevent Notifications of Stub Comments in Google Plus?

Tags: google-plus

Situation: I receive too much notifications of stub comments in groups of Google plus
Examples: Yes; No; Your are welcome; `thank*`; .`*[1,99]`, ...
Motivation: no productforum of Google for Google plus so thread here
Related in Inbox: 
[How to Filter/Categorise Stub Emails in Inbox?](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/inbox/Kz6KAG9_krM;context-place=forum/inbox)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot by default settings. A feature request is sent to the developers about it.